# Por que estos archivos no se me integran al tema de wordpress

Tags: php, html5, wordpress, wordpress-theme, responsive

Buen dia, formulo esta pregunta ya que estoy tratando de integrar un archivo con propiedades css a WORDPRESS donde tengo todo lo relacionado a lo responsive y el tema no me esta aplicando los cambios lo mismo pasa con el archivo .js que quiero agregar, lo que me parece mas raro es que la plantilla me esta tomando los estilos css del archivo style.css pero los del responsive.css no me los toma

para los sagregar los estilos css utilice estas etiquetas

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>">
```

para el archivo responsive.css utilice esta funcion

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/responsive.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

Actualmente wordpress recomienda la utilización del siguiente método para agregar los archivos tanto css como los js a los temas y no colocandolo en el header.php.
Debes agregar la siguiente función en el functions.php (cambia las "xxx" por el nombre de tu tema):

```
function xxx_scripts() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

  //cambia el "main" por el nombre del archivo css y la ruta por la tuya
  wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_theme_file_uri('css/main.css') );

  //para agregar los scripts se emplea lo siguiente de la misma forma que el anteior:
  wp_enqueue_script ('main', get_theme_file_uri('js/main.js') );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'xxx_scripts' );
```